# Multi-Force Lift

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, simulations, moment

Background: I am creating a 3D game. A ship has 3 thrusters that apply force up (Z+) to counteract the force of gravity (Z-).

I am trying to figure out how much thrust to apply to each thruster to get the ship to hover. I have:

- The total force needed to counteract gravity
- All thrusters are pointing down, so they are all tangent to the ship.
- Distances to each thruster, relative to the CG of the ship
- I know that I also want the sum of all moments to equal 0. (Just stable hover at this point)

That only gives me 2 equations for 3 unknowns it seems. What am I missing?

Force Total = Force Front + Force Left + Force Right

Moment Front = Transform Front XProd Force Front

Moment Left = Transform Left XProd Force Left

Moment Right = Transform Right XProd Force Right

Moment Total (0) = Moment Front + Moment Left + Moment Right

Thanks all.

**Edit** for clarity.

Ship from the bottom, thrusters pointing downward (so thrust vector would be up)
[image: Bottom of ship]

Comment: What are the angular positions of the thrusters in the plane of the thrusters?

Comment: Just to make sure, is this a three dimensional setup or two dimensional setup? It sounds like three dimensional.

Comment: 3 Dimensional game. All thrusters are perpendicular to the ship pointing down. Edited question for clarity. Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your geometry, I would solve it this way.

Based on symmetry, your front thruster has no roll authority.  So in hover, the left rear and right rear must be equal.  (1)

Use the lever arm front and rear of the front thruster by itself and the rear thruster pair to eliminate any pitch moments. (2)

Total thrust to match weight. (3)

Since they're all pointing down, they are all parallel to the yaw axis, and you have no yaw control.

---

If you're interested in the general solution, pick one thruster (labeled as $C$) and place it on the forward axis.

[image: Triangle graph for thruster position.]

1. Same as before, null the roll by setting the ratio of $A$ and $B$. Since we don't assume symmetry here, use the lever arm ratios.  $T_A x_A = T_B x_B$
2. Null the pitch by setting the relative strength of $C$.  $T_C y_C = T_A y_A + T_B y_B$
3. Set all 3 to sufficient thrust to equal weight.  $T_A + T_B + T_C = W$

Three equations, three unknowns ($T_A, T_B, T_C$)

Comment: I'm going to be devil's advocate here and look for a more general solution where I don't have to have symmetry and could place the thrusters arbitrarily. Thanks for your input!

Comment: Great answer, diagrams and everything. That looks like what I'll need. Thanks a lot for your input.

Answer (score 1):

You also need the total thrust to balance the weight of the ship.  That is your third equation.  You have guaranteed that the ship does not rotate, but it could accelerate vertically (either up or down).

Comment: I actually have that as my first equation, I've calculated the total force I need to get my desired vertical speed (Z axis)

Comment: The moment total is in two axes.  You need to compute the moment in each of $x$ and $y$.  That gives two equations.  You need to compute the moment of each thruster in each axis.  If your $x$ axis is along the centerline and the CG is also along that line, one (the $x$ axis torque) will say the two aft thrusters have the same thrust.  The $y$ axis torque equation will relate the thrust of the front one compared to the two aft ones.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that you need three equations for three unknowns. In addition to the total thrust equaling the vehicle weight, you need to establish horizontal axes at right angles to each other and calculate the net moment of the three thrusters about each axis. The net moment about each axis must equal the moment of the vehicle weight about those axes. So you need to know the location of the vehicle's center of gravity. For simplicity choose one axis going through two of the three thrusters, and the other axis at 90° going through the third thruster.